# working LocationClient always returns null after turning location services on and off again

Tags: android, google-play-services, location-client

OK, so this is really freaky...

I switch from the old locationmanager to the new shiny locationclient a while back. Works fine, but i noticed a very strange thing while testing fringe settings cases:

As i said, working positoning app using google play's LocationClient as per examples etc.

I start my app, get a couple of positions, all work fine. (You could say that i have a button that fetches locations when you click on it)

I go into settings/location. I disable "Google location services", go back into app, get nothing. I then go back and reenable the setting!

However - i get nothing. ever. Even if i restart my app i never get a location it times out every time.

Only if i restart the phone i start getting positions again.

Anybody have any ideas? Thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Try open Maps after enabling the service. No need to restart.